# We need a simple 'Off topic' close reason

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

I wanted to vote close question https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/9888, but there is no appropriate close reason other than writing one myself.

I suggest we have a simple:

> Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with earth science)

... possibly expanded to

> ... as described in the [help] section of the site

Comment: Absolutely. There used to be one, but somehow it vanished when the new rock-identification one was put in. There's **got** to be room for both.  (I procrastinated over asking this myself).

Answer (score 3):

This should now be live, as I just approved a new custom close reason:

> This question does not appear to be about earth science, within the scope defined in the [help center](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/help).